# Command line for JPA-based classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Is there any way I can generate a database or update its structure with a command line tool using my JPA-annotated project classes? I'm using Hibernate 4.3.7 as a JPA provider and Spring 4.1.2 as general configuration and wiring handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://jandrewthompson.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-generate-ddl-scripts-from.html)

Or just use `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` in your config to update automatically on start.